# real positive symmetric matrix and its square root

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A\in M_{n}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ be a symmetric matrix with positive eigenvalues.
Show that there exists a symmetric matrix $\sqrt{A}\in M_{n}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, which has the same eigenspaces as $A$ and has only positive eigenvalues, and which satisfies $\left(\sqrt{A}\right)^{2}=A$.
My attempt:
Because $A$ is symmetric there exist an orthogonal matrix $O$ and diagonal matrix $D$ s.t $A=ODO^{t}$ and I found that $\sqrt{A}=O\sqrt{D}O^{t}$
I was able to prove the part about the positive eigenvalues, and that $\sqrt{A}$ is symmetric and satisfies $\left( \sqrt{A}\right)^{2}=A$, but I can't prove the fact that they have the same eigenspaces. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for a matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$. For every pair $(\lambda_i,v_i)$ of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we have that $Av_i=\lambda_iv_i$. We also have that $B^2v_i=\lambda_iv_i$ since $A=B^2$, which means that $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $B^2$, and thus $B$ since $B$ is symmetric and, hence, diagonalizable.

Let $\mu_i$ be the eigenvalue of $B$ associated with $v_i$. Then, we have that $B^2=\mu_i^2v_i$. This implies that $\lambda_i=\mu_i^2$. Therefore, $\mu_i=\pm \sqrt{\lambda_i}$ is associated with the eigenvector $v_i$. Since, we are interested in the positive definite square-root, then we just pick the positive values.

Now, since $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, then we have that $A=P^TDP$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ on the diagonal and $P$ is such that $P^TP=PP^T=I$

Now, define $B=PD^{1/2}P^T$. Then, we have that $$B^2=PD^{1/2}P^TPD^{1/2}P^T=PDP^T=A.$$

Comment: How $Bv_{i} = \lambda_{i}v_{i}$ if $B$ is $\sqrt{A}$?

Comment: And how come $B^{2} = \mu_{i}^{2}v_{i}$

Comment: @mathlover The first one is a typo. The second one follows from the definition. If $Bv_i=\mu_iv_i$, then $B^2v_i=\mu_i^2v_i$.

Comment: in the first paragraph, you said "since $A = B^{2}$, which means that $v_{i}$ is an eigenvector of $B$ and thus $B^{2}$, why is that? if $B^{2}v_{i} = \lambda_{i}v_{i}$ we can conclude that $Bv_{i}$ is an eigenvector of $B$, but not $v_{i}$ itself

Comment: This is the case as $B$ is symmetric and, hence, diagonalizable.